# Android: EditText Line doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-view

I can't get the line that indicates where to enter the text in EditText in Android Studio 2.2.1.
Everything else works fine including EditText. 
TargetSDK is 23 and MinSDK is 15.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_one"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="in.shopperstreet.delta.One"
android:background="#5bf7cd">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/siva_txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txt"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_above="@+id/siva_btn"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="47dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
    android:width="30dp"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: screenshot of my activity]

Comment: did you try to set fix width and height for it ?

Comment: Yes.But not getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the height and width of the `EditText` as `wrap_content`.

Give a hint as:

```
android:hint="hiiiiiii"
```

inside the `EditText` text tag, you will see where it exists

If you just want to add a line, add a `View` below the `EditText` like this:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="47dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="47dp"/>
```

Comment: If i give the hint, i can see where it exists.

Comment: If i give a hint, i can perceive where it exists.But i need to get a line underneath.Have added 'width' to EditText.

Comment: That's where it exists, but its not visible because the width and height is set to wrap_content

Comment: @SivaPrakash have updated the answer to add the line, and you dont give width with android:width="30dp", so remove that line and add the width to android:layout_width="100dp"

Comment: Got it.Is this the correct way to get a line underneath EditText or a workaround ? Thank you.

Comment: EditText's don't have a line undernearh by default, its just the styles and it will change with different API levels. So this is a workaround and will be same with all API levels

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_above="@+id/siva_btn"` is not defined anywhere so you can remove it .Here is my improved version of code of  your editext

```
     <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="47dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
    android:width="30dp"/>
```

and the result is this
[Showing edittext line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcyVR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go for [MaterialEditText](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText) for better performance.

Answer (score -2):

You should change layout_width (of EditText) to match_parent or fixed size, or use

```
android:hint = "           ";
```